# Longer than intended loop due to multiple variables

Tags: python, function, loops, python-2.7

I'm making a program that charts a random movement across a grid, where the starting point is the middle of the grid and the user gives the number of columns and rows. The current problem is that I have two changing variables that both need to signal the end of program. X is for horizontal movement and Y is for vertical: if either of them go outside of the grid, I need the program to end. At the moment, when one variable goes off, it continues running until the other does. (Ex. If it moves off the grid vertically, the program still keeps picking random directions and moving horizontally. The same it true for horizontal.) So I'm not sure how to write the program so that it ends when one of them goes off, instead of waiting for both. Here's what I've got so far:

```
import random
def rightmove(width, px):
px += 1
if px > width:
    return px
else:
    return px

def leftmove(width, px):
px -= 1
    if px == -1:
    return px
else:
    return px

def downmove(height, py):
py += 1
if py == height:
    return py
else:
    return py

def upmove(height, py):
py += 1
if py == -1:
    return py
else:
    return py

def main():
height = raw_input("Please enter the desired number of rows: ")
height = int(height)
width = raw_input("Please enter the desired number of columns: ")
width = int(width)
px = round(width/2)
px = int(px)
py = round(height/2)
py = int(py)
print "Manhattan (" + str(width) + ", " + str(height) + ")"
print "(x, y) " + str(px) + " " + str(py)
topy = height + 1
topx = width + 1
while 0 <= px <= width:
    while 0 <= py <= height:
    s = random.randint(0, 1)
    if s == 0:
        x = random.randint(0, 1)
        if x == 0:
            px = leftmove(width, px)
            if px <= 0:
                print "Direction E (x, y) " + str(px)
            else:
                print "Direction E"
        else:
            px = rightmove(height, px)
            if px <= width:
                print "Direction W (x, y) " + str(px)
            else:
                print "Direction W"
    else:
        y = random.randint(0, 1)
        if y == 0:
            py = downmove(height, py)
            if py <= height:
                print "Direction S (x, y) " + str(py)
            else:
                print "Direction S"
        else:
            py = upmove(height, py)
            if py <= 0:
                print "Direction N (x, y) " + str(py)
            else:
                print "Direction N"


main()
```

Here's a sample of the intended output:

```
>>> manhattan(5,7)
(x, y) 2 3
direction N (x, y) 1 3
direction N (x, y) 0 3
direction S (x, y) 1 3
direction W (x, y) 1 2
direction S (x, y) 2 2
direction E (x, y) 2 3
direction S (x, y) 3 3
direction W (x, y) 3 2
direction N (x, y) 2 2
direction W (x, y) 2 1
direction E (x, y) 2 2
direction W (x, y) 2 1
direction N (x, y) 1 1
direction N (x, y) 0 1
direction S (x, y) 1 1
direction W (x, y) 1 0
direction E (x, y) 1 1
direction W (x, y) 1 0
direction W
```

Comment: You'll have to fix your indentation, I'm afraid. Your code is unreadable as it stands.

Comment: what are you editing your code with? If you set your editor to 4 spaces per tab and add an extra tab you should be able to paste it as is onto the site.

Comment: You don't even need to add an extra tab; just copy and paste it as-is, then select what you pasted and click the "code" button.

Comment: Just went through and fixed the indentations. Hopefully it's easier.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is only a guess without seeing your actual indented code, I believe your problem is this:

```
while 0 <= px <= width:
    while 0 <= py <= height:
        # a whole mess of logic
```

If `py` goes out of bounds, you'll escape the inner loop, but then just keep repeating that inner loop until `px` also goes out of bounds.

If `px` goes out of bounds, you'll still be stuck inside the inner loop until `py` also goes out of bounds.

What you want is to escape as soon as *either* goes out of bounds. In other words, you want a single loop, that keeps going as long as both are in bounds. Which you can translate directly from English to Python:

```
while 0 <= px <= width and 0 <= py <= height:
    # same whole mess of logic
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `while` loops with proper indentation would look like this:

```
while 0 <= px <= width:
    while 0 <= py <= height:
        s = random.randint(0, 1)
        if s == 0:
            x = random.randint(0, 1)
            if x == 0:
                px = leftmove(width, px)
                if px <= 0:
                    print "Direction E (x, y) " + str(px)
                else:
                    print "Direction E"
            else:
                px = rightmove(height, px)
                if px <= width:
                    print "Direction W (x, y) " + str(px)
                else:
                    print "Direction W"
        else:
            y = random.randint(0, 1)
            if y == 0:
                py = downmove(height, py)
                if py <= height:
                    print "Direction S (x, y) " + str(py)
                else:
                    print "Direction S"
            else:
                py = upmove(height, py)
                if py <= 0:
                    print "Direction N (x, y) " + str(py)
                else:
                    print "Direction N"
```

If this is what you've got, then the solution is simple. First, change `if px <= 0:` and `if py <= 0:` to both use `>=`.

Then, add return statements after each of the print statements that mean you are done. For example:

```
if px >= 0:
    print "Direction E (x, y) " + str(px)
else:
    print "Direction E"
    return
```

If you use return statements, then instead of two nested `while` loops you can simply use `while True:`.

Or, if you prefer, you can change the condition of the `while` loops as abarnert suggested and not worry about putting in return statements.

Comment: If you do that, the nested `while` loops aren't doing anything; you might as well have a single `while True`. And if you're going to fix the `while` loops, you don't need the `return` statements.